Approach to validating an Azure MSAL session across B2C
We have a frontend that authenticates through an azure B2C custom policy - user flow, adds user to tenant - all good. We get back what we need from the client in that respect and the user is logged in.
The correct approach to the next step seems difficult to get a handle on based on helper libraries and official MS docs...
We have a separate backend which we want to call after the client MSAL login. The idea is that some middleware might check if the user calling it has an active session in azure in order to legitimately carry out their API operation of choice. This backend doesn't live in Azure.

Workings:
It looks as though the MSAL method getAccountByHomeId could be what I need.
I have this POC code mocked up which takes the homeAccountId stored in the browser and is used on the BE to simulate the header pass:
const clientConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: config.authOptions.clientId,
    authority: config.authOptions.authority,
    redirectUri: config.authOptions.redirectUri,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    knownAuthorities: config.authOptions.knownAuthorities,
  }
};

const confidentialClientApplication = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
  clientConfig
);
const msalTokenCache = confidentialClientApplication.getTokenCache();
const byHomeId = await msalTokenCache.getAccountByHomeId(
  ${homeAccountIdHeaderVal}
);
console.log("byHomeId", byHomeId); // returns null

Problem:
Getting null returned from this call.
Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.
